# Is it possible to add topic to Rviz from command line?

Tags: ros, rviz, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want my topics to be added automatically to Rviz. Is it possible??

Wanted to know whether there are commands to add topics

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256940/is-it-possible-to-add-topic-to-rviz-from-command-line??/) by [shashankbhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/29689/shashankbhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, that is not possible.

But you can tell RViz to load a particular *configuration* at startup, using the `-d` command line arg.

See `rviz -h` for more info.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shashankbhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/29689/shashankbhat/) on 2017-03-14**:
Thanks alot @gvdhoorn